# Min and max-width mess up text-align center

Tags: html, css

The fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uK7w6/1/

```
<h1>this is a really, really long sentence</h1>

h1 {
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

If you get rid of the max and min width, the sentence centers fine, but I want it to center as well as not take up the whole width. Why does the text align left when I add width constraints?

Comment: It doesn't, for me.  Chrome 32.0.1700.76

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 26.

Comment: Setting both min and max width to the same value is the same as just setting width.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The text within the `h1` is actually centered, but it is centered within a `100px width box`. If you want the h1 to float in the middle of the `window` then add a `margin:0 auto;`. The primary reason that the `h1` is aligned to the left has to do with the `display:box` property.

```css
h1 {
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>this is a really, really long sentence</h1>
```

Comment: what does `margin:0 auto;` do?

Comment: it removes the default left and right margin of 0 allowing it to "free-form" to its parent element. By setting it to `auto`, you essentially tell it to not worry about the left or right margin which places the element in the middle. I've never had to actually describe the `auto` value, so my wording could be incorrect.

Comment: what about the top and bottom margins? how does it know to only remove the default 0 for the left and right?

Comment: because you are setting the top and bottom values to 0

Answer (score 1):

Heading1 is a block-level element.
But text-align property in CSS is used for aligning the **inner content of** a block element(`inline and inline-block` elements)

So your `text-align` **won't do anything to a `block element` itself** but really can center the contents in the `block element`.
Check this out:

[The Reason Why Max-Width MessUp Text-align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbt20.png)

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: gray;
  height:5vh;
}
.withMaxWidth {
  max-width: 60%;
}
.inline-block {
  display:inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
<article class="container">
  <p class="item">A normal block element seems centered</p>
  <p class="item withMaxWidth">A max-widthed block element</p>
  <p class="item inline-block">An inline-block element centered by text-align</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the word 'sentence' is more than 100px wide and by default text only breaks at spaces. Change it to the following [although it can make it harder to read]:

```
h1 {
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  // Non standard for webkit
  word-break: break-word;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Or make it wider. You could center it with margin: 0 auto; - but the word sentence still wont be centred within the h1.

Edit: This may be what you're actually trying to achieve.

If you want to force each word on a new line and keep the longer words centered you could do the following:

```
h1 {
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

<h1>this 
is 
a 
really, 
really
long
sentence</h1>
```

white-space: pre-line; will put a line break where ever there is a line break in the html. You will still have to make the whole element as wide as the widest word though.

http://jsfiddle.net/uK7w6/1/